# Kannel: maybe Sim storage is full? I'll have a look at it.(500)

Tags: sms, kannel

The server was sending SMS properly, but at a moment of time I got this error: ERROR: Unknown error. -> maybe Sim storage is full? I'll have a look at it. (500)

Here are my logs:

```
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: TP-Validity-Period: 24.0 hours
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: --> AT+CMGS=17^M
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: <-- >
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: send command status: 1
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: --> 0011000A8170440674530000A704E872390F
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: --> ^Z
2016-05-25 14:24:53 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: <-- >
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: send command status: 1
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: handling message (0x7f2934000fc0 vs 0x7f2934000fc0)
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: re-queing SMS not-yet-to-be resent
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: handling message (0x7f2934000fc0 vs 0x7f2934000fc0)
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: re-queing SMS not-yet-to-be resent
2016-05-25 14:25:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: time to sleep 30.00 secs.
2016-05-25 14:25:18 [27725] [6] DEBUG: AT2[A]: <- +CMS ERROR: 500
2016-05-25 14:25:18 [27725] [6] ERROR: AT2[A]: CMS ERROR: +CMS ERROR: 500
2016-05-25 14:25:18 [27725] [6] ERROR: AT2[A]: CMS ERROR: Unknown error. -> maybe Sim storage is full? I'll have a look at it. (500)
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: gwlist_len = 1
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: handling message (0x7f2934000fc0 vs 0x7f2934000fc0)
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: re-queing SMS not-yet-to-be resent
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: handling message (0x7f2934000fc0 vs 0x7f2934000fc0)
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: re-queing SMS not-yet-to-be resent
2016-05-25 14:25:44 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: time to sleep 30.00 secs.
2016-05-25 14:26:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: gwlist_len = 1
2016-05-25 14:26:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: sms_router: handling message (0x7f2934000fc0 vs 0x7f2934000fc0)
2016-05-25 14:26:14 [27725] [7] DEBUG: Message routed successfully.
```

I tried to fix it using:

- I had configured max-messages = 100 for group = sendsms-user and restarted the server, but same result
- I had configured sim-buffering = true and message-storage = "SM" and restarted the server, but same result

I already checked:

- The SIM has credit.
- The receiver phone number is correct.

Thanks for help,

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked. Just upgrade kernel to 1.4.5 or 1.5.0 the add to:

```
group = modems

message-start = 0
```

After that didn't happen any more, hope this will work for you.